# Sandbox Amazon Payments - Access Key Id

Tags: amazon-web-services, payment

I want to integrate amazon payments in my site. Where can i get the access key, signature, amazon Account id for sandbox account to implementing amazon payments?
Please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

All of these can be found in [Seller Central](https://sellercentral.amazon.com).

Make sure `Amazon Payments Advanced` (Sandbox or Production) is selected in the drop-down at the top of the page!

MWS Access Key:

Click `Integration > MWS Access Keys`: This will show you the access key and secret keys.

Seller ID:

Click `Settings in the upper right > "Integration Settings`: This will have your `Merchant ID` which is your `Seller ID`.

If you do not see `Amazon Payments Advanced` in the drop-down you need to sign up for an account. You can do that [here](https://payments.amazon.com/signup).

Comment: And what should I do if I don't see any drop-down menu on the top of the list? I see only "Login with Amazon" text

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, if you do not see "Amazon Payments Advanced" you will need to add it to your account. Since you already have a Seller Central account you can click Settings > Account Info > Modify Plan. Pick "Login and Pay with Amazon" then Register.

Comment: It's the Select Box drop-down that would have www.amazon.com, www.amazon.ca, Log In With Amazon, etc ... not to be confused with the drop-down menus from the other navigation links in the header.